# Expresion regular (javascript) 10 numeros y dos decimales

Tags: javascript

Hola tengo la siguiente funcion que me limita hasta dos decimales pero me deja escribir cualquier cantidad de numeros enteros, quiero que me limite a 10
¿Cómo quedaría el pattern?

```
var preg = /^([0-9]{10}+\.?[0-9]{0,2})$/;
```

lo he intentado asú pero no funciona

Comment: Por qué dices que no funciona? Con qué dato lo estás probando?

Comment: porque con ese pattern, no me valida los 10 numeros se sigue hasta el infinito y ya cuando pongo el punto si me limita a dos cecimales
^([0-9]{0,2}\.?[0-9]{0,2})$ esto ya me limita a 10 enteros pero no me reconoce el punto

Comment: La  razón por la que permite mas de 10 dígitos es por `+` lo cual indica 1 o mas

Answer (score 1):

`^([0-9]{1,10}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?)$`

Intenta con esa.

Explicación de cada parte:

`[0-9]{1,10}`: Es el que limita de 1 a 10 digitos.

`(\.[0-9]{1,2})?`: La parte de los decimales es opcional, por eso el `?`. `\.` para que escriban un punto antes de los decimales. `[0-9]{1,2}` limita los decimales de 1 a 2 digitos.

Prueba con 10 enteros y punto decimal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Prueba con más de 10 enteros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ASí si me limita los 10 enteros pero ya no me deja meter el punto

Comment: Esa expresión no me deja colocar el punto

Comment: Sí deja, te puse unas imágenes de unas pruebas que hice en https://regexr.com/